# Показать еще без использования ajax

Tags: javascript

Как сделать кнопку "показать еще" без использования ajax?

Comment: А чем мешает AJAX?

Answer (score 2):

```
<button>показать еще</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Выгрузить всё что есть на страницу в скрытый блок и потом показывать по чуть чуть.

з.ы. Какой вопрос такой ответ